# What permissions does my application have, starting up on boot? (HKLM\...\Run)

Tags: windows, permissions, startup, uac, privileges

My application is starting up on boot, because it's registered in *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run*.

I can't change that right now, but I'm clearly running into permission problems, that prevent me from creating files in some folders.

My application runs fine when started manually by the user (without admin permissions). But it can't create files when it is started automatically on boot.

**So my question is**: What permissions exactly does an application have, when it is started automatically? Is this documented somewhere?

I just read somewhere that it might run as a Non- or Least-Privileged User. Still, I'm wondering what permissions they might have, since I don't find this well documented.

I'm running VS2017, C# .NET 4.0, Windows 10 1803, if that's important.

Answer (score 1):

An [application registered under](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/setupapi/run-and-runonce-registry-keys)

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Both cause a program to run when a user logs in. The program runs with the permissions of the user that is logging in.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I fixed it by checking the path used to write the target file. First, I use only the target file name. In this way, the system uses the directory path from where you launch the app. (I don't know where that is.) Then, I used the full app `.exe` file name, including file path, minus the `.exe`'s file name, thus getting the app's `.exe` file path. In this way, I can be sure where the app writes the target file. (The app's `.exe` directory.)

For example, `c:\myfolder\myapp.exe` - `myapp.exe` = `c:\myfolder\`.

Using:

```
SQLScript1.Script.SaveToFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+ FormatDateTime('yyyy_mm_dd_hh_nn', now)+'.dat');
```

Previously, I had done it the following way:

```
SQLScript1.Script.SaveToFile( FormatDateTime('yyyy_mm_dd_hh_nn', now)+'.dat');
```

...and it fails only at startup. If I run the app by double-clicking the `exe` file, it works fine.

Comment: Okay, I think that makes more sense. I've cleaned up the grammar, punctuation, and formatting a bit and edited that into your original answer. Thanks for working with me on this.